# Why is kmalloc() more efficient than vmalloc()?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, page-tables

I think `kmalloc()` allocates continuous physical pages in the kernel because the virtual memory space is directly mapping to the physical memory space, by simply adding an offset.

However, I still don't understand why it is more efficient than `vmalloc()`.
It still needs to go through the page table (the kernel page table), right? Because the MMU is not disabled when the process is switching to the kernel. So why Linux directly maps the kernel virtual space to the physical memory? What is the benefit?

In `include/asm-x86/page_32.h`, there is:

```c
#define __pa(x) ((unsigned long)(x)-PAGE_OFFSET)
#define __va(x) ((void *)((unsigned long)(x)+PAGE_OFFSET))
```

Why does the kernel need to calculate the physical address? It has to use the virtual address to access the memory anyway, right? I cannot figure out why the physical address is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your Queries :-

- **why is Kmalloc more efficient than vmalloc()?**

kmalloc allocates a region of physically contiguous (also virtually contiguous) memory. The physical to virtual map is one-to-one.

For vmalloc(), an MMU/PTE value is allocated for each page; the physical to virtual mapping is not continuous.

vmalloc is often slower than kmalloc, because it may have to remap the buffer space into a virtually contiguous range. kmalloc never remaps.

- **why Linux directly maps the kernel virtual space to the physical memory?**

There is one concept in linux kernel known as DMA(Direct Memory Access) which require contiguous physical memory. so when kernel trigger DMA operation we need to specify physically contiguous memory. that's why we need direct memory mapping.

- **Why the kernel needs to calculate the physical address? It has to use the virtual address to access the memory anyway, right?**

for this question answer you need to read difference between virtual memory and physical memory. but in short, every load and store operation is performed on physical memory(You RAM on PC)

physical memory point to RAM.

virtual memory point to swap area of your HARD DISK.

Comment: Thank you. For the last one, I thought virtual memory means the virtual memory addresses given to the MMU while physical memory means the physical memory addresses calculated by MMU. It seems I misunderstood these terms.

Comment: But from the code in "include/asm-x86/page_32.h", it seems that virtual memory is indeed the virtual memory addresses given to the MMU, and physical memory is indeed the physical memory addresses calculated by MMU? As the load and store instructions use virtual addresses as operands, why does the kernel need to calculate the physical addresses? MMU will do it anyway.

Comment: @hebothu see one or two sentences can not help you to understand memory management in Linux. You have to go through the concept of mmu. But in simple terms, virtual memory is the illusion only. Actaul memory which is used for get and put data is your ram which refer as physical memory.

Comment: To understand virtual memory you can take simple example, like a postman, a postcard bear a address but postman does not know it is right address or not. so first he reach at your state. He try to match your home address. To get your home address he takes help of people or GPS. Once he gets your home address, he reach at your address and deliver your packet. Your home address is physical memory, GPS or people is MMU, who send you postcard is cpu, address on postcard is Virtual address and your state is hard disk (swap area). Hope you understand.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and your comments. Due to my poor English, however, I don't know if I really stated my question clearly. Now I guess that the __pa(x) macro is used to initialize the page table. If that is the truth, it completely makes sense to me.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding "virtual memory point to swap area of your HARD DISK". Could you please provide me some references to help me understand this? Thanks :)

Comment: The statement *virtual memory point to swap area of your HARD DISK* is wrong for the kernel.  Virtual memory maps to either physical via a page table or to swap via a fault (and also an invalid page table w. ind of backing store) in user space.  All kernel memory is pre-mapped with `kmalloc`.  With `vmalloc` an additonal **PTE** must be made (consuming some memory) and additionally, the TLB/page-hit/table walk will apply when using the memory.  For kernel functionality, it is often needed to know the physical address and this becomes much more difficult.